# How do we prove $4 + \frac {|?|}{n^2} + \frac {|?|}{n^3} + \frac {|?|}{n^4} + \frac {|?|}{n^5} < 4 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1$?

Tags: inequality

I came across the line below when reading a proof. There was no justification given. Does it need to be proven?

> $4 + \frac {|a|}{n^2} + \frac {|b|}{n^3} + \frac {|c|}{n^4} + \frac {|d|}{n^5} < 4 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1$ EXCEPT for finitely many $n.$

edit: Need to prove that $f(n) = 4n^5 - \frac {n(n + 1)(n + 2)}{3} + 3n^2 - 12$ is $O(n^5)$. We multiply out all the terms in $f$ so we get $f(n) = 4n^4 + an^3 + bn^2 + cn + d$.

Then $|f(n)| = |4n^5 + an^3 + bn^2 + cn + d| \le 4n^5 + |a|n^3 + |b|n^2 + |c|n + |d|$.

We divide the expression by $n^5$ and get $\frac {|f(n)|}{n^5} = 4 + \frac {|a|}{n^2} + \frac {|b|}{n^3} + \frac {|c|}{n^4} + \frac {|d|}{n^5}.$

Comment: And what does $|?|$ mean?

Comment: Unless you tell us more, it's hard to know what you're asking. For example, take $|?|=n^5$, showing the inequality is false in general.

Comment: @Grumpy Parsnip, I edited my OP.

Comment: You should denote the coefficients ? by $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ instead; it would be clearer and you still don't have to compute their values. Also, it looks like the three instances of $4n^4$ should be corrected to $4n^5$.

Comment: @epimorphic, done.

Comment: Perhaps this will help...  You have $f(n) = 4n^5 - \frac {n(n + 1)(n + 2)}{3} + 3n^2 - 12$.  This can be rewritten as $f(n) \approx O(n^5) - \frac {n(n + 1)(n + 2)}{3} + O(n^2) + O(1) \approx O(n^5) - \frac {n(n + 1)(n + 2)}{3}$.  The first rewrite is because we know that the terms are asymptotically bounded by the Landau notations given (the Big-Oh notations).  The second is because we can combine the Landau notations together.  So You're left with a term $n(n+1)(n+2)/3$. There are at most 3 powers of $n$, so this is $O(n^3)$.  Does this help?  I can explain more...

Comment: @Meshuggah: thanks. I've now upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a,b,c,d$ denote constants, let $t=\max\{|a|,|b|,|c|,|d|\}$. Then, if $n>t$, you have
$$
\frac{|a|}{n}<\frac{t}{n}<1,\quad
\frac{|b|}{n^2}<\frac{t}{n}<1,\quad
\frac{|c|}{n^3}<\frac{t}{n}<1,\quad
\frac{|d|}{n^4}<\frac{t}{n}<1
$$
How many are the positive integers $n$ such that $n\le t$?

Comment: If $t = n = 1$, then all the terms will be $1$. If $t = n > 1$, then all the terms but  $ \frac {|a|}{n} > 1$. If $t = 2$ and $n = 1$, then  all the terms will be greater than $1$.For all $t = 2 + n$, only $ \frac {|a|}{n} > 1$. Are those the number of exceptions?

Comment: @Meshuggah First of all, I take $n>t$. The exceptions are the numbers $1,2,\dots,\lfloor t\rfloor$.

Comment: if $n > t$, then the inequality holds for all $n$. But what about the question about the number of $n >0$ such that $t \ge n$? Did I misunderstand that?

Comment: @Meshuggah Those are the possible exceptions.

Comment: I see. Why is $t$ enclosed inside floor function symbol?

Comment: @Meshuggah Just to get an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n_0 = max (|a|,|b|,|c|,|d|)$. Then the inequality holds for all $n>n_0$. Hence, it is false for only finitely many $n$.

Comment: Are there more than one $n_0$? If so how do we know? Also, why do we use the "max" notation here. Never seen it before.

Comment: @Meshuggah The "max" notation only means that we choose the maximum value of $|a|, |b|, |c|$ and $|d|$. This $n_0$ is just one I have chosen to show you that the statement holds true. However, there are infinitely more $n_0$'s that one could choose and still get the right result.